# Zend ACL allow certain actions

Tags: zend-framework, acl

How do I use the Zend ACL to allow access to certain users to some of the actions within a controller? Right now, I only know how to allow a user to access the whole controller, but I want to limit the actions within the controller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow/deny access to certain actions, specify them in the allow/deny methods of Zend_Acl.

The third argument in the `Zend_Acl::allow()` method will only allow you to set access controls to certain actions on a given controller/resource. For example:

```
<?php

$acl = new Zend_Acl();

// Roles
$guest = new Zend_Acl_Role('guest');
$user = new Zend_Acl_Role('user');

// Register the roles with the Zend_Acl
$acl->addRole($guest);
$acl->addRole($user, 'guest');

// Resources/Controllers
$indexController = new Zend_Acl_Resource('index');
$profileController = new Zend_Acl_Resource('profile');

// Add resources/controllers to the Zend_Acl
$acl->add($indexController);
$acl->add($profileController);


// Now set limits of access to the resources.
// Guests get access to all the actions in the index controller,
// but to only the login and logout actions in the profile controller.
$acl->allow('guest', 'index');
$acl->allow('guest', 'profile', array('login', 'logout'));

// Users get full access to the profile controller
$acl->allow('user', 'profile');
```